# Einstellung oder Einrichtung?

Tags: difference, german-to-english, vocabulary, comparison

Ich möchte wissen, was der Unterschied zwischen *Einrichtung* und *Einstellung* ist. Der Zusammenhang, um den es mir geht, ist „Setting“.

Comment: Nachdem ich verschiedene Einstellungen am Bürostuhl vorgenommen hatte war seine Einrichtung für den Mitarbeiter abgeschlossen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Einstellung* ist die passende Übersetzung zu "setting". Eine Einstellung steht hier für einen speziell hergestellten (*eingestellten*) Zustand an. Der Duden gibt diese Bedeutung in Definition 3a) zum Wort [einstellen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einstellen) an.

*Einrichtung* bezieht sich auf den Akt einen geplanten Zustand zu erreichen (siehe Duden zu [einrichten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einrichten)). Man kann daher seine Einstellungen einrichten (z.B. wenn man zum ersten Mal eine App öffnet). Im Sinne von "setting", habe ich Einrichtung aber noch nie verstanden.

Comment: "Einrichtung" entspricht eher "setup" als "setting".

Comment: Zitat: _“Man kann daher seine Einstellungen einrichten“_. Das ist so nicht richtig. Nicht die Einstellungen selbst werden eingerichtet, sondern die App, und zwar indem man Einstellungen vornimmt.

Answer (score 5):

Das Wort *Einstellung* wird in der Regel dann gebraucht, wenn es um den Zustand *eines* bestimmten Parameters oder *einer* bestimmten Größe geht:

> Die Einstellung des Temperaturwerts ist zu hoch.
>
> Ich kümmere mich um die Positionseinstellung der Kamera.
>
> Bei der neuen Software lassen sich verschiedenste Einstellungen vornehmen.

Gelegentlich ist auch der Vorgang des *Einstellens* gemeint:

> Beim Einstellen/ bei der Einstellung ist etwas schief gelaufen.

Das Wort *Einrichtung* wird verwendet, wenn *mehrere* Parameter oder *mehrere* Größen so eingestellt werden, dass das Gerät oder die Software betriebsbereit ist. In diesem Sinne ist es ein Synonym zu *Konfiguration*. Auch hier werden *Einrichtung* und *Konfiguration* gelegentlich dann verwendet, wenn der Vorgang des *Einrichtens* oder *Konfigurierens* gemeint ist:

> Beim Einrichten/ bei der Einrichtung/ bei der Konfiguration/ beim Konfigurieren des PCs ist ein Fehler unterlaufen.
>
> Der Techniker ist für das Einrichten/ die Einrichtung/ die Konfiguration/ das Konfigurieren der Anlage verantwortlich.

Zusammengenommen lassen sich mit *Einstellung* und *Einrichtung* Sätze wie die folgenden bilden:

> Nachdem ich alle Einstellungen vorgenommen hatte, war die Einrichtung des PCs abgeschlossen.

Comment: Der Schlusssatz trifft es genau!

Comment: Interessanterweise gibt es im Maschinenbau den Beruf des *Einstellers*, der nicht nur einzelne Parameter *einstellt*, sondern die gesamte Maschine *einrichtet* - Und dann gibt es noch den *Einrichter*, der typischerweise auch noch die passenden Werkzeuge auswählt. Und im Pferdesport gibt es auch noch einen *Einsteller*, der aber nur sein Pferd irgendwo dazustellt.

Answer (score 3):

Gehen wir mal davon aus, dass Du von EDV-Systemen sprichst:

Eine *Einstellung* ist ein vom Benutzer oder Entwickler änderbarer Wert der Konfiguration einer Software.

Die *Einrichtung* einer entsprechenden Software umfasst normalerweise sowohl die Installation und Integration in einem EDV-System, sowie auch die Konfiguration (die eventuelle Änderung einzelner Einstellungen).

*Einstellung* wäre für mich die Übersetzung von *setting*, *Einrichtung* entspräche eher *setup* oder *configuration*.

Aber auch in anderen Bereichen gilt:

Um die Einrichtung von etwas abzuschließen (= benutzungsfertig zu machen) müssen gegebenenfalls einzelne Einstellungen geändert werden.